# How to perform parallel reduction to sum an array

Tags: parallel-processing

I'm new to parallel programming and can't quite grasp the concept of how to implement parallel reduction.
Say you were to sum a vector of 128 floats in shared memory with 8 threads how would you achieve this with only 2 for loops?

The only way I can think of is to sequentially add the vector until you're left with 16 elements that you can compute in parallel but that wouldn't be much faster than just sequentially adding all the elements together?

Answer (score 0):

You can **assume the sum of two floats is associative**.

Based on this, you can then virtually **divide the vector** in 8 equal parts and compute **each part in each thread** (in parallel). Each thread can make a *local* sum and then put this in a cell of a predefined array `local_sums`.
Finally, one thread can make the sum `local_sums` resulting in the global sum.

Note that the sum of floating-point numbers is **actually not associative** (the result of `a+b` and `b+a` are *marginally different*).
However, you cannot parallelize the code if you do not make this assumption. Furthermore, the difference of precision of the two methods is generally similar (ie. not great for both).